# Implementing Plugin Functionality in Firmware using FreeRTOS, LittleFS, and gcc-arm-none-eabi

Tags: plugins, embedded, cortex-m, freertos

I am currently working on a project involving firmware development for Cortex-M microcontrollers (NXP RT1175). My development stack includes FreeRTOS, LittleFS, and the gcc-arm-none-eabi toolchain. I am looking to implement a "plugin" functionality in this firmware, where my clients can write their own algorithms and deploy them independently.

The main challenge I'm facing is designing a system where these plugins can be dynamically loaded (only once at startup) and executed by the firmware. The plugins should be able to interact with the existing functionalities (APIs and functions) provided by the firmware. Here are some specifics:

- **Firmware Base**: The firmware is not currently compiled as Position-Independent Code (PIC), and I'm using various frameworks like FreeRTOS and LittleFS.
- **Plugin Requirements**: The idea is for clients to compile their plugins separately using the same toolchain (gcc-arm-none-eabi). The plugins need to call functions defined in the firmware, which means they need to know the entry points of these functions.
- **Current Approach**: I am considering using a file system approach (via LittleFS) where the firmware would look for plugin files in a specific directory and load them into RAM for execution. Plugin can be compiled as PIC.

I have a few questions regarding this setup:

1. **Best Practices for Plugin File Format**: What would be an appropriate file format for these plugins considering the current toolchain and frameworks? I'm thinking about code and data memory that need to be loaded at different RAM adresses.
2. **Handling Function Entry Points**: Since the firmware is not currently compiled as PIC and the function addresses might change with each compilation, what would be the best approach to let the plugins know about these function entry points?
3. **Security and Stability**: How can I ensure the security and stability of the system when loading and executing third-party plugins?

Any guidance, suggestions, or references to similar implementations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic loading is normally a function of an OS and FreeRTOS does not natively support that.

VxWorks is an example of an RTOS that can dynamically load and link object modules. The modules are generated by [partial linking](https://downloads.ti.com/docs/esd/SPNU118/partial-incremental-linking-stdz0756731.html) whereby the object is generated with some external symbols unresolved. VxWorks in this case has a dynamic loader that resolves the external links in the loaded object to the existing code on the target.

To achieve that the target requires a complete symbol table to be present.  This is not conducive to very small foot-print systems - especially if you are supporting linking C++ code.  The same symbol table is used in the VxWorks command shell to run loaded or static code.  Essentially any function with external linkage becomes an entry point, so for example typing `printf "hello"` in the command shell does exactly what you would expect.  You would only need a naming convention such as `pluginMain()`.  VxWorks has a means of searching the symbol table and you could use pattern matches to find plug-ins.

However I would not recommend any of that.  It is fundamentally insecure to load an link arbitrary code to your core binary.

A safer, simpler and more secure solution would be to embed a scripting language interpreter such as [Lua](https://www.lua.org/ddj.html) or [MicroPython](https://micropython.org/).  I once worked on a product were we enabled end-user customisation using Forth (though I'd hesitate to recommend that!), or you could implement your own proprietary scripting language (fun, but non-trivial).  You can then expose only the interfaces that you want your end-users to be able to use, and not effectively give them free reign throughout your code.